# mongoose update multiple conditions with fallback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to have ONLY ONE endpoint that can do 2 things to make the front end job easy. This endpoint can update age and grade, either one can be optional. Below code will fail if age or grade is not present. How to fix this?

```
//update age and grade
app.put('/user', function(req, res) {
  var date = req.body.date,
  userId = req.body.userId,
  age = req.body.age,
  grade = req.body.grade;

  Trucks.update({'date':date, 'id': userId}, {'$set': {
    'userData.$.age': age,
    'userData.$.grade': grade
  }}, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).json({
            error: 'Error update update user\'s data'
        });
    }else{
        res.send(response);
    }
  })
});
```

Can I put condition in the update object?

```
{
    age ? "'userData.$.age': age", : ''
    grade ? "'userData.$.grade' : grade" : ''
}
```

Hmm don't think so..

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare the query before send to mongoose, for example.

```
//update age and grade
app.put('/user', function(req, res) {
  var date = req.body.date,
  userId = req.body.userId,
  age = req.body.age,
  grade = req.body.grade;

  var query = {};

  if(age){
    query['userData.$.age']= age;
  }

  if(grade){
    query['userData.$.grade']= grade;
  }

  Trucks.update({'date':date, 'id': userId}, {'$set': query}, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).json({
            error: 'Error update update user\'s data'
        });
    }else{
        res.send(response);
    }
  })
});
```